# Flatten nested json array to simple array in javascript(remove nesting)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nested

I want to flatten my json nested array object to flat array

Both key and value pair should be dynamic as per the user input array

I tried to code myself but I am not much familiar with JavaScript function to do concat, push or other funtions.

Input:

```
{
  "ReportID": "ProfitAndLoss",
  "ReportName": "Profit and Loss",
  "ReportType": 7,
  "ReportTitles": [
    "Profit & Loss",
    "Clearlight Saunas Australia Pty Ltd",
    "1 May 2017 to 31 May 2017"
  ],
  "ReportDate": "17 May 2017",
  "UpdatedDateUTC": "2017-05-17T05:52:23.414Z",
  "Attributes": null,
  "Fields": [],
  "Rows": [
    {
      "RowType": "Header",
      "Cells": [
        {
          "Value": "",
          "Attributes": null
        },
        {
          "Value": "31 May 17",
          "Attributes": null
        }
      ],
      "Title": null,
      "Rows": null
    },
    {
      "RowType": "Section",
      "Cells": null,
      "Title": "Income",
      "Rows": [
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Curve Dome Sauna",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "a76bacdc-a411-4924-9860-7c8b1bf36e5b",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Value": "6725.46",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "a76bacdc-a411-4924-9860-7c8b1bf36e5b",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        },
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Essential Sauna Sales",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "b2544842-1e51-4c08-80bc-7077f01a8657",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Value": "21359.09",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "b2544842-1e51-4c08-80bc-7077f01a8657",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        },
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Premier Sauna Sales",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "7f5bb82f-f488-441e-b578-c3e6d16829f0",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Value": "19088.18",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "7f5bb82f-f488-441e-b578-c3e6d16829f0",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        },
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Revenue - Installation ",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "e4985303-4ce7-4162-9ed3-e9a7799b5584",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Value": "636.36",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "e4985303-4ce7-4162-9ed3-e9a7799b5584",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        },
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Sanctuary sauna sale",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "90bda37d-e484-494c-8ad5-dd012f6acb56",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Value": "26244.55",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "90bda37d-e484-494c-8ad5-dd012f6acb56",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        },
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Sauna cover sale",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "5a1aa34f-9acb-4154-8d4c-bb7e56a16cc8",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Value": "727.27",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "5a1aa34f-9acb-4154-8d4c-bb7e56a16cc8",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        },
        {
          "RowType": "SummaryRow",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Total Income",
              "Attributes": null
            },
            {
              "Value": "74780.91",
              "Attributes": null
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "RowType": "Section",
      "Cells": null,
      "Title": "",
      "Rows": [
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Gross Profit",
              "Attributes": null
            },
            {
              "Value": "74780.91",
              "Attributes": null
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "RowType": "Section",
      "Cells": null,
      "Title": "Plus Other Income",
      "Rows": [
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Sauna Sale to Clearlight NZ Ltd",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "12eca2ea-00ff-4f1a-9187-bd3faaf15eae",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Value": "1309.09",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "12eca2ea-00ff-4f1a-9187-bd3faaf15eae",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        },
        {
          "RowType": "SummaryRow",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Total Other Income",
              "Attributes": null
            },
            {
              "Value": "1309.09",
              "Attributes": null
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "RowType": "Section",
      "Cells": null,
      "Title": "Less Operating Expenses",
      "Rows": [
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Bank Fees",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "1ee9c97a-5707-4289-9d40-fa25d2f087d3",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Value": "503.54",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "1ee9c97a-5707-4289-9d40-fa25d2f087d3",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        },
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Sauna Storage",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "f3813ca9-9a0f-4c31-8afb-a1f9af61ca9a",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Value": "670.00",
              "Attributes": [
                {
                  "Value": "f3813ca9-9a0f-4c31-8afb-a1f9af61ca9a",
                  "Id": "account"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        },
        {
          "RowType": "SummaryRow",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Total Operating Expenses",
              "Attributes": null
            },
            {
              "Value": "1173.54",
              "Attributes": null
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "RowType": "Section",
      "Cells": null,
      "Title": "",
      "Rows": [
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Net Profit",
              "Attributes": null
            },
            {
              "Value": "74916.46",
              "Attributes": null
            }
          ],
          "Title": null,
          "Rows": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the desired output i want:

```
[
 {
     "ReportID": "ProfitAndLoss",
     "ReportName": "Profit and Loss",
     "ReportType": "7",
     "ReportTitles": "Profit & Loss",
     "ReportDate": "17 May 2017",
     "UpdatedDateUTC": "2017-05-17T05:52:23.414Z",
     "Attributes": null,
     "Rows__RowType": "Header",
     "Rows__Cells": "",
     "Rows__Cells____Value": "",
     "Rows__Cells____Attributes": null,
     "Rows__Title": null,
     "Rows__Rows____RowType": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Value": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Value": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Id": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Title": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Rows": "",
     "Rows__Rows": null
 },
 {
     "ReportID": "",
     "ReportName": "",
     "ReportType": "",
     "ReportTitles": "Clearlight Saunas Australia Pty Ltd",
     "ReportDate": "",
     "UpdatedDateUTC": "",
     "Attributes": "",
     "Rows__RowType": "",
     "Rows__Cells": "",
     "Rows__Cells____Value": "31 May 17",
     "Rows__Cells____Attributes": null,
     "Rows__Title": "",
     "Rows__Rows____RowType": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Value": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Value": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Id": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Title": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Rows": "",
     "Rows__Rows": ""
 },
 {
     "ReportID": "",
     "ReportName": "",
     "ReportType": "",
     "ReportTitles": "1 May 2017 to 31 May 2017",
     "ReportDate": "",
     "UpdatedDateUTC": "",
     "Attributes": "",
     "Rows__RowType": "Section",
     "Rows__Cells": null,
     "Rows__Cells____Value": "",
     "Rows__Cells____Attributes": "",
     "Rows__Title": "Income",
     "Rows__Rows____RowType": "Row",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Value": "Curve Dome Sauna",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Value": "a76bacdc-a411-4924-9860-7c8b1bf36e5b",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Id": "account",
     "Rows__Rows____Title": null,
     "Rows__Rows____Rows": null,
     "Rows__Rows": ""
 },
 {
     "ReportID": "",
     "ReportName": "",
     "ReportType": "",
     "ReportTitles": "",
     "ReportDate": "",
     "UpdatedDateUTC": "",
     "Attributes": "",
     "Rows__RowType": "",
     "Rows__Cells": "",
     "Rows__Cells____Value": "",
     "Rows__Cells____Attributes": "",
     "Rows__Title": "",
     "Rows__Rows____RowType": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Value": "6725.46",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Value": "a76bacdc-a411-4924-9860-7c8b1bf36e5b",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Id": "account",
     "Rows__Rows____Title": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Rows": "",
     "Rows__Rows": ""
 },
 {
     "ReportID": "",
     "ReportName": "",
     "ReportType": "",
     "ReportTitles": "",
     "ReportDate": "",
     "UpdatedDateUTC": "",
     "Attributes": "",
     "Rows__RowType": "",
     "Rows__Cells": "",
     "Rows__Cells____Value": "",
     "Rows__Cells____Attributes": "",
     "Rows__Title": "",
     "Rows__Rows____RowType": "Row",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Value": "Essential Sauna Sales",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Value": "b2544842-1e51-4c08-80bc-7077f01a8657",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Id": "account",
     "Rows__Rows____Title": null,
     "Rows__Rows____Rows": null,
     "Rows__Rows": ""
 },
 {
     "ReportID": "",
     "ReportName": "",
     "ReportType": "",
     "ReportTitles": "",
     "ReportDate": "",
     "UpdatedDateUTC": "",
     "Attributes": "",
     "Rows__RowType": "",
     "Rows__Cells": "",
     "Rows__Cells____Value": "",
     "Rows__Cells____Attributes": "",
     "Rows__Title": "",
     "Rows__Rows____RowType": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Value": "21359.09",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Value": "b2544842-1e51-4c08-80bc-7077f01a8657",
     "Rows__Rows____Cells__Attributes____Id": "account",
     "Rows__Rows____Title": "",
     "Rows__Rows____Rows": "",
     "Rows__Rows": ""
 }]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store this json in a variable and make use of something like

```
JSON.parse(variable_name);
```

After this it's in the form of an array and you can easily loop through it

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am expecting code. I know how this can be done but I am not much familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: @DurgeshSharma the answer has provided you with code to get started.

Comment: true, @DurgeshSharma , this thing will get you started, we guys are always here to help you, you can always post your future doubts here as well

Comment: Can you write a code for this ? I want those key and value pair both dynamic as per the input array

Comment: Ohk I will try to do it later in the day but tell me first on what basis the rows should be created ? like based on number of rows or what ?

Comment: Yes, based on number of objects in that array. This can be done by a recursive function which will loop through each nested array recursively